# Javascript - Array that stores and returns numbers associated with string titles provided by the user

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, multidimensional-array

I have searched and tried many array options for this and I can't seem to figure it out. At first the script just needed to store and return a number associated for each month.

For example the user would provide a number (say 200), for month 1. I would store the number 200 in an array within index 1. Now when I needed to update or retrieve that number I would just reference Array[1]. Simple.

Now they want to provide more information. They want to provide a number associated with a unique string that could be anything, like "element5", or "department2", for the month 1.

Now I need to be able to call an array like this Array[1]["element1"] to store and retrieve the number.

I understand javascript does not support named indexes, nor can I even get it to dynamically create a named index.

Most answers on here are recommending using sequential numbered indexes instead of dynamically named indexes or variables, but isn't that impossible in this situation when the user wants to provide a string.

The reason it is so important to use the string provided by the user, is if they again enter that string, we expect to be able to find that value and replace/increment it.

Comment: You can use plain object : `array[1]={"element1":200}`.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your data?  I can't tell if you're saying they want you to store it in an object or not.  Is it  `[{ "element1": 1}, {"element2": 2}]`  ? It would be best if you showed an example of what it looks like now and how you want it to look formatting wise in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [GrouchyPanda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47915594/635631) , you could use an object:

```js
var data = {}

data['month1'] = 200
data['whatever'] = 300

console.log(data['month1'])
```

Alternatively, if you **must** use an array, you can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
data = [
  {key: 'month1', value: 200},
  {key: 'whatever', value: 400}
]

item = data.find((i) => i.key == 'month1')
console.log(item.value)
```

In case you're not familiar with ES6 syntax, `(i) => i.key == 'month1'` is short for `function(i) { return i.key == 'month1' }`.

Comment: I had heard an array was a type of object, but I have always used array's in my scripts. This is working great, I am using the first example you provided. I can create an object for each month and it allows me to save/access a value for every string the user enters. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! In JS, think of arrays as sequential lists of values. Think of objects (in this case) as dictionaries with arbitrary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to store the value as an array, you should look into just storing it as objects. Indexing in that instance can be whatever you want as the key.

You could then access your values using notation like `arr.1.stringName`
Edit: The above line is incorrect as mentioned int he comment. A proper access would be like so
`arr['1'].stringName`

Comment: `arr.1.stringName` is a Sytnax Error. It is effectively tokenized as as [`arr`, `.`, `1.` (a number literal), `stringName`] which has no corresponding grammar production. Code *must* use `[]` notation for numeric indices or for properties that are not valid literals: JavaScript literals cannot start with numbers.